# I cant get back into Ubuntu after turning off my Acer c710 Chromebook

Tags: acer, chromebook

I took about 1 hour installing Ubuntu to my Acer chrome book. I turned off my computer and now it boots back into Chrome OS (yes i know its supposed to) Then i went onto the Chrome OS dev terminal thing and put in the code sudo cgpt -i 6 -p 5 -s 1 /dev/sda. Nothing happens it comes up with another Local Host slot. I tried using the Ctrl Alt f2 and ctrl alt f3 but nothing happened. I really need to get back onto Ubuntu. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your chromebook is in developer mode, then open a crosh window. depending on what kind of ubuntu desktop you downloaded, run this command: sudo startunity

or: sudo startxfce4

and so on...

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

when you turn it back on, I assume the exclamation point page shows up? when you see this, press enter. It will make 2 beeping sounds. You will still end up in the OS environment, but it leaves you in developer mode so that your ubuntu key combo should work. Hope this works!

Comment: actually after entering the OS environment you will most likely have to enter a terminal (ctrl alt T) shell, then sudo start(whatever desktop you downloaded).

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of commenting.